# В чем разница ticket_id=56412 и ticket_id like '%56412'?

Tags: mysql, sql, devops

Мы знаем что есть всего 7 записей с ticket_id=56412. Записей с ticket_id > 60000 нет, никаких символов перед 56412 нет. Как могла появиться разница в количестве?

- **SELECT count(*) FROM tickets_messages WHERE ticket_id=56412;** *возвращает 5 записей*
- **SELECT count(*) FROM tickets_messages WHERE ticket_id like '%56412';** *возвращает 7 записей*

Comment: Ну то посмотрите записи, которые возвращаются, в чем отличие.

Comment: Какой тип данных у поля? небось строковый? проверяй на ведущий пробел...

Comment: не знаю что за тип, наверное интежер, у меня такой вопрос был в тестах на стажировку, я никак не могу найти, я сам добавил 7 записей туда и применял эти запросы, у меня оба воврщают 7 записей, но там мне ответили что не правильно, в чем может быть разница?

Comment: *не знаю что за тип, наверное интежер* Ну так узнай!

Comment: там нету этого, ну если тип варчар будет разница? а если интежер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, ticket_id VARCHAR(255));
> INSERT INTO test VALUES 
> (1,56412), 
> (2,'.56412'), 
> (3,'-56412'),
> (4,' 56412 '),
> (5,'X56412');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test WHERE ticket_id=56412;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | ticket_id
> -: | :--------
>  1 | 56412    
>  4 |  56412
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test WHERE ticket_id like '%56412';
> ```
>
> ```
> id | ticket_id
> -: | :--------
>  1 | 56412    
>  2 | .56412   
>  3 | -56412   
>  5 | X56412
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=308859176ea056288488e9712f647a43)*

Comment: я так как понял ticket_id это int, а условия такие Записей с ticket_id > 60000 нет, никаких символов перед 56412 нет. но у вас перед 56412 есть символы

Comment: @IskandarXolboyev Отрицательное значение полностью соответствует всем этим условиям.